# What is the simplest method to redirect traffic using either a proxy or iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables, proxy

I need to redirect all incoming traffic on port 7777 to a specific destination_ip:port.

I have about 40 Litecoin (scrypt) mining rigs that I have to manually reconfigure each time I'd like to switch coins or pools.  Instead I would like to be able to just modify the destination address on my proxy box to direct the farm.

I am currently using Dante proxy which has a redirect module available that looks perfect.  I don't have $400 to spend on that module however.  Also, Dante seems to take up huge amounts of memory for every connection.

Also, instead of using a proxy, I tried using iptables as a solution but received an error:

```
root@xx:~# iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d x.x.x.x --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to x.x.x.x:7777
root@xx:~# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d x.x.x.x -j MASQUERADE
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

I could not get that to work nor am I sure if that would even be a solution to what I'm after.

Any ideas on how to best achieve my desired result would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d x.x.x.x --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to-destination y.y.y.y:port
```

You need to provide the destination and port specified as arguments on **`to-destination`**.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: If you did some "dirty" changes (you tried things that did not work), restart iptables to clean them. If you saved your changes even if they did not work, then you should clean those rules (use `-D` option) before trying to add more.

---

First, make sure you accept incoming packets:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT
```

Then redirect the traffic (consider `-I`, for inserting the rule at the beginning; sometimes is better than appending the rule to the chain):

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to-destination <destination_ip>:<destitation_port>
```

You can check the rule you just added (you should see something like `DNAT [...] tcp dpt:7777 to:<destination_ip>:<destitation_port>` and probably you should not see other rules in the `PREROUTING` chain related to that specific port):

```
iptables -L -n -t nat
```

If everything works well, always remember to save your changes (otherwise, you will lose the rules after restart/reboot):

```
service iptables save
```